# How to convert numeric string object to nullable numeric

Tags: c#

With the following example, two calls are made to ConvertNumericStringObj, it sends back a Type int object both times.

```
string strValue = "123";
object obj = ConvertNumericStringObj(typeof(int), strValue);
object obj = ConvertNumericStringObj(typeof(int?), strValue);   

public static object ConvertNumericStringObj(Type conversion, object value)
{
    var t = conversion;
    if (t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)))
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t);
    }
    return Convert.ChangeType(value, t);
}
```

My question is: Is there someway to pass in the string and `int?` Type and convert it so it returns a `int?` object?

Comment: For string to int conversion use: Int.TryParse()

Comment: You cannot have a boxed `Nullable<T>`. The runtime has special boxing behavior for nullables. If an object reference is a boxed `T` then it can always be converted to a `T?`.

Comment: See mike z's comment. That said, if you can change the method, you could make it generic and have it return T instead of object. That would get around the boxing restriction on Nullable<T>. Then you also would have to continue the code in the Nullable<T> special case that already exists (which is there because Convert.ChangeType won't convert to Nullable<T>), to convert to the underlying type and rewrap it in a Nullable<T> to return it. It's a lot of trouble to go to, but if you have to have do things this way, it can be done.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I think your right. Too much trouble in the end I need to compare these values as well, which nullables don't do. So this just means handling the nulls carefully and converting to their underlining Type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the types to potentially be **either** `int` or `int?`, then what you're looking for is "generics". This should get you what you want.

```
public static T ConvertNumericStringObj<T>(string value)
{
    var t = typeof (T);
    if (t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
    {
        if (string.isNullOrEmpty(value))
            return default(T);

        t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t);
    }
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, t);
}
```

**However**, I'm curious why you wouldn't just return a nullable integer resulting from `int.TryParse()` instead.

```
public static int? ConvertNumericStringObj(string value)
{
    int? x;

    if (int.TryParse(value , out x)
        return x;

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I am not very fluent on generics, but not sure that this work however, this would mean that when calling I'd have to set the `T' Type explicitly wouldn't it? Which unfortunately is not what I'm after.

Comment: You might want to rethink what you're trying to do with this method. How would you consume the return value, if you don't know what underlying type to expect? You should either **always** return a nullable type (i.e. pass in `int?` to the generic method above) or always know what specific type (e.g. `int` or `int?`) when you call the generic method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Try `Int32.TryParse`.

```
public static int? ConvertNumericStringObj(string strValue)
{
    int x;
    if (Int32.TryParse(strValue , out x)
        return x;
    return null;
}
```

But I wonder, if you necessarily need to pass `int?` ?

**Edit:** as OP asked it to be a little generic, try extension method (roughly) like,

```
public static T? ConvertNumericStringObj<T>(string strValue) 
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue))
        return null;
    return (T) Convert.ChangeType(strValue, typeof(T));
}
```

This way, you can then use as:

int? x = strX.ConvertNumericStringObj();

Comment: All you've done is take away the type parameter.  Now it can't handle other types.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I don't think, OP cared for other types. he said, `My question is: Is there someway to pass in the string and int? .. `

Comment: My mistake in the title, my apologies on that, I did mean for it to be generic.